# How to pass varadic paramters to macro from a templated function?

Tags: c++, macros, variadic-templates

I want to implement a function some similar to `verify` in Unreal 4, where if some expression is not true, print the tag and some variable used in the expression.
Here is a case:

```
int x = ...;
long y = ...;

Verify( x > y, "check-range", x, y);
Verify( y < INT_MAX, "check-range:y", x, y, INT_MAX);
```

The solution I supposed was bellowing function `Verify`, and I want to join all the paramters to one string in macro `GET_STRING_FROM_PARAMETERS`. But I didn't figure out the way how to pass varadic paramters to macro from a templated function.

Here is the code:

```
#define GET_STRING_FROM_PARAMETERS(...) \
    do {                                                      \
        if (...) {                                            \
            something to be done                              \
        }                                                     \
    } while (false)

template <typename... Ts>
constexpr void Verify(bool expression, const std::string &tag, Ts &&... rest) noexcept {
    if (!expression) {
        std::cout << tag << " " << GET_STRING_FROM_PARAMETERS(rest...);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to use a macro and not a simple free function?

Comment: Your macro seems unsuitable for the purpose even without trying to pass a parameter pack to it. Why do you think you need a macro at all?

Comment: Logically, it would be the other way, having a MACRO `Verify` to be able to stringify the variable `x, y` and have the pair name/value.

Comment: You can't. Macros are expanded before templates are expanded. You have to put something in the macro that makes it so after the macro is expanded, the template expander knows what to do

Comment: @Heto I did want `Verify` to be a function, no matter what kind of object `GET_STRING_FROM_PARAMETERS` is.

Comment: @user253751 Got it. I should make it to be a function or somewhat.

Answer (score 2):

Your code will not compile for multiple reasons. You are using macro a a function  while it's  containing a while statement, you're passing parameter pack directly to it, parameter pack can't be used like that in loop.

You can't pass parameter pack to macro because preprocessing happens *before* compiling code. Macro definitions are not aware of templates. You have to use a trick to maintain proper syntax:

```
 #define PARAMETER_PACK(x)  x...

 #define SOME_OTHER_MACRO(x)  auto lm = \
                    [&, PARAMETER_PACK(x)] { return foo(PARAMETER_PACK(x)); }

 SOME_OTHER_MACRO(Args);
```

The ellipsis cannot be part of argument list for functional macro. It can be a part of expression within that list, so you also can do this in some cases:

```
#define SOME_OTHER_MACRO(x) g x;

SOME_OTHER_MACRO((Args ...));
```

It's a limited and weird way in both cases, preferably do not use macrodefinitions in such templates at all. Use smaller auxiliary templates if you must.

Comment: Got it. It should be a function to solve macro expanding error.